# Java function local variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a selection-sort program and I get a compilation error when I try to display the `arr[index]` value after my second for loop.

Error:

> `j` cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int index = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
            System.out.println(arr[index]);
            if (arr[j] < arr[index])
                index = j;

        int smallerNumber = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = smallerNumber;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Don't indent your code yourself. This questions shows, why this is error-prone. Let your IDE indent your code for you.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `{` and `}` in the inner `for-loop` so **the scope of the loop ends when the first `;` is found**. Then: `j` is not present in the `if` condition...

```
public static int[] doSelectionSort(int[] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int index = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        //                                       ↑  here!
            System.out.println(arr[index]);
            if (arr[j] < arr[index])
                index = j;
        }
    //  ↑  here!

        int smallerNumber = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = smallerNumber;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: to add to this: if you don't add them, the scope of the for loop ends at the first ; encountered.

Comment: thanks @Stultuske. I added it to my answer... i always though it was all the first line and not until first `;` !!! **Nice point**

Comment: It's usually the first line, but if the sop line wouldn't have been there, it would have been the first two lines. (there again, if brackets were used ... )

Comment: Well, it's more like the scope of the `for` loop ends after the end of the next _statement_, but since statements ends with a `;` or with a `}` it is almost the same :D.

Answer (score 1):

You got to use {} after your second for loop

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
    System.out.println(arr[index]);
    if (arr[j] < arr[index])
       index = j;
```

to:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
    System.out.println(arr[index]);
    if (arr[j] < arr[index])
        index = j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the variable j in the loop, it's local to the loop so without the braces, you cannot use this variable like you wanted to do.